# Problem in moving my Codeigniter site from live server to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, web-applications

I am moving my  CodeIgniter site from live server to localhost. 
I have downloaded the files via ftp and database file from Phpmyadmin then i set everything and configured database. 
But the problem is only my homepage is accessible no login or form submission is happening whatever i do i am redirected to home but that is not the case on live server.
I cant understand whats the issue why its working perfectly fine on live server but not on localhost.

I think the problem is that sessions are not working because i cant login. Below are my config file session settings.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400; //7200
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300; //300
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'app';
$config['cookie_domain']    = 'localhost';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/app/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Comment: Check your server error logs to see if there's anything there. As it stands, this question is too broad until you can narrow down what is causing it.

Comment: Check the routing, class and functions and also check the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this solution from [Codeigniter session data lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472869/codeigniter-session-data-lost-after-redirect) by @user2818832
it worked for me.!

if you are working in CI 3.x and just upgraded your server php version to php 7.x

Go to system/libraries/Session/session.php at Line no 281 and replace ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']); by ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);

Comment: Ok but why is this solution works? And why codeigniter programmers don't fix this problem like this for a long time?