# Codeigniter 3 - additional session in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, session-variables

I am struggerling with the Session:

When I call https://example.com/index.php/objects/index/260 I get this:

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1614171352)
```

When I call https://example.com/objects/index/120

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1614171373)
```

So, two different sessions! Why do I get an additional session here?

Is this related to the htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Bests,
yab86

Comment: not 2 different sessions, session regenerated. You can see what is inside a session using `print_r($_SESSION)`

Comment: Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1614171373) is the result from print_r($_SESSION).

Comment: the session has been regenerated and the value you are getting is the UNIX timestamp.

Comment: Solved it. Found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472869/codeigniter-session-data-lost-after-redirect Changed ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']); to ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']); in session.php. Works now! :-)

Comment: @yab86 Please close your question (or add [Solved] to the end of the title)