# PyroCMS / Codeigniter : too many session entries in db

Tags: database, codeigniter, session, pyrocms

I'm using for a small website the pyrocms / codeigniter combo. 
after adding some content, i checked the db and saw that:
[image: multiple session id's]

is this a normal behaviour? multiple session_ids for one user with the same ip?
i can't imagine that this is correct.

my session config looks like:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'pyrocms' . (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production' ? '_' . 

ENVIRONMENT : '');
$config['sess_expiration']      = 14400;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = true;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = true;
$config['sess_use_database']    = true;
// don't change anything but the 'ci_sessions' part of this. The MSM depends on the 'default_' prefix
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'default_ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = true;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = true;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

i did not change on line of code affecting the session class or something like that.

the red hat rows belong to a 15min cron-job. this is fine i think.

everytime a refresh the page two or three new session_entries are added...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2438835/183254 anything in there help?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i'm afraid not ;(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. The CI session class automatically generates a new ID periodically. (Every 5 minutes, by default.) This is part of the security inherent in using CI sessions instead of native PHP sessions. Garbage collection will take care of this, you do  not need to do anything.

You can read more about the session id behavior in the [CI manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). This is an excerpt copied from that page.

> The user's unique Session ID (this is a statistically random string
>   with very strong entropy, hashed with MD5 for portability, and
>   regenerated (by default) every five minutes)

This behavior is by design. There is nothing to fix. The session class has built in garbage collection that deletes old entries as needed. I have many projects using code igniter for several years. This is what it does.

If it really bothers you, you can alter the timeout in the main CI config file. Change the line

> $config['sess_time_to_update']    = 300 (the 5 minute refresh period)

to a number greater than

> $config['sess_expiration'] (default 7200)

This will cause the session to timeout before it is regenerated. This is inherently less secure in theory, but unless you are transacting sensitive data, it is probably irrelevant in practice.

But again, this is by design as part of the many layers of CI sessions. These and other features are what make it better than PHP native sessions. You can turn on profiling and see that the overhead for these queries is negligible, especially in light of all the other optimizations the framework provides.

Comment: The manual doesn't mention anything about the 5 minute update nor the id behavior. But, looking at the [source](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_cookie.php#L520) it looks like it does regenerate every 5 minutes, but also looks like it tries to update the existing session if match ip and/or match user agent is set. Think this would fix the dupe entries?

Comment: lengthened my answer to take into account your comments

Comment: I have one little blind spot in my left eye...that must have been where that line was ;) Thanks for expanding your answer.

Comment: YW. I hope this answers all the questions.

Comment: But the Session IDS will be created on -every- Page refresh. How would you explain that?

Comment: That I am not sure about, I have not seen that behavior in my work. Is it possible you have outdated or modified system files? It would be easy to delete your system folder and drop in the current version to check. Make a backup first, naturally.